# How to use RDP protocol in Remote Desktop Viewer?

Tags: 11.04, remote-desktop, live-usb, rdp

I am using a Natty Live-USB, and the **Remote Desktop Viewer** application (Applications -> Internet -> Remote Desktop Viewer) **only shows `SSH` & `VNC`** protocols.

**How can I include `RDP` in the list**, in order to connect to existing [Windows Remote Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) sessions on Windows XP machines.

I am aware that I can use the `gnome-rdp` application, or even `rdesktop hostname` from a terminal, but I would like to create a persistent LiveUSB that uses Remote Desktop Viewer to connect to Windows RDP (port 3389).

I do not want to set up `VNC`, `TeamViewer` or any others, as these do not solve my problem due to the fact they need additional software on the remote hosts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The versions of `vinagre` (the application you mention) included with all released versions of Ubuntu do not support the RDP protocol (the feature was added in 2.31.4, while Ubuntu 11.04 comes with 2.30.3).

So there are basically three options:

1. Wait for a new Ubuntu version with an updated version of `vinagre` (the next release should be sufficient).
2. Use some other application to connect to RDP servers such as `tsclient`.
3. Acquire an updated version of `vinagre` from some other source.

Comment: While `tsclient` is probably the correct application to use, I intend to try updating the `vinagre` package to a version that supports RDP in order to try and answer the question. [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vinagre) doesn't list a release for 2.31.4, and [3.0.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/gnome/vinagre) will have too many dependancy issues.

Comment: The 2.31.x series are development releases, so it isn't too surprising that it wasn't packaged.  It looks like they moved to GTK 3 with the subsequent developer release, so there isn't a stable version with RDP that is targeted at GTK 2.  You may be able to update the Natty packaging to work with the 2.31.4 development release though.

Answer (score 1):

As the description says, *Remote Desktop Viewer* aka `vinagre` supports SSH and VNC.

The standard tool used in *Ubuntu* for RDP is *Terminal Server Client* aka `tsclient`, so use that.

Answer (score 1):

Vinagre does not support the rdp protocol. I would recommend either the default "Terminal Server Client", which offers a whole lot of options, and the `remmina` client, which is quite similar to vinagre, and offers RDP as well.